# How to sort a hash with a value inside it

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I've a hash

```
H = { abc: [1,1,2], def: [0,1,1], efg: [3,4,7] }
```

How to sort descending these with the last index of the array i.e., I need the hash to be like this `H = { efg: [3,4,7], abc: [1,1,2], def: [0,1,1]}`

```
H.values[2].sort
```

Comment: Actually i want it to be ordered hash to preserve the data inside..  let me re-frame it. Suppose i have the data of 5 students with the no. of backlogs in even sem and odd sem and total backlog. Key is the students name say "abc" and value is a list having backlogs in odd sem, even sem and total [0,1,1] ... Each element of the hash is like "abc"=>[0,1,1] and i need to order it so that i get the student with the most backlogs first then second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it into an array then back into a hash:

```
x = {a: [1,2,3], c: [7,8,9], b: [4,5,6]}
x.sort_by { |k,v| v.last }.reverse.to_h
# => {:c=>[7, 8, 9], :b=>[4, 5, 6], :a=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

`sort_by` turns it into array of  tuples:

```
x.sort_by { |k,v| v.last }
# => [[:a, [1, 2, 3]], [:b, [4, 5, 6]], [:c, [7, 8, 9]]]
```

Of course you can call `.reverse` to get descending order

and you can call `.to_h` on this data structure to make a hash again.

Although, it's not normal to think of hashes as ordered structures, I think they do actually preserve order but usually if you are working with ordered data you will keep it as an array. I would question why you need to use an ordered hash.

Comment: ...or `x.sort_by { |k,v| -v.last }.to_h`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland true :D

Comment: Actually i want it to be ordered hash to preserve the data inside.. I don't think you understood my question let me re-frame it.  Suppose i have the data of 5 students with the no. of backlogs in even sem and odd sem and total backlog. Key is the students name say "abc" and value is a list having backlogs in odd sem, even sem and total [0,1,1] ...  Each element of the hash is like "abc"=>[0,1,1] and i need to order it so that i get the student with the most backlogs first then second.

Comment: @NirmalBhakat what is "sem"? No offense but your language isn't very clear.

Comment: semester or half-year

Comment: @NirmalBhakat: "so that i get the student with the most backlogs first then second" - and code in this answer does just that.

Comment: @NirmalBhakat Answer is appropriate to question and example  provided. If you have any scenario missed from answer, Please edit question with case explained with input data.